# Adding a listener to remove scroll function if width < x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this css style set up to remove the sidebar behaviour on `#sidebox` when the screen gets smaller than 1024px in width. Also it gets replaced to its original location where it serves as a normal div within the content, hence the: 'position: relative'.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #sidebox {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

The next step*(This is what I need help with)* is to remove the JQuery script that makes `#sidebox` scroll to the top when it gets below a certain height, but still let it behave that way when the screen is larger than 1024px.
So when resizing the screen over 1024px `#sidebox` should scroll to the top. This behaviour is known as 'following'.
Below is the JQuery script I have set up to accomplish what is stated above:

```
if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $("#sidebox").css("top", Math.max(0, 120 - $(this).scrollTop()));
    });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
        $("#sidebox").css("top", Math.max(0, 120 - $(this).scrollTop()));
    } else {
        $("#sidebox").css("top"), 0;
    }
});
```

So how can I help you ask? Well, as you might have guessed it, the behaviour is flawed.

`#sidebox`*(in css)* `<div id="sidebox">...</div>`*(in html)* does only behave desirably if the site is refreshed.
It appears that `$(window).resize` is not functioning as a listener for resizing.

So when my window is 1920px in width and I open the site the sidebar will function as desired, but when I resize my window to a width lower than 1024px it will go to its proper location because of the css seen above, but still try to scroll, because `$(window).resize` does not function as I wish it to.

Comment: Shouldn't your if statement be inside the scroll event, not outside of it, that way the scroll either works or doesn't based on window width *when the scroll happens* rather than on page load? you seem to already be doing this in the resize event.

Comment: Don't you mean to write: $("#sidebox").css("top", 0); rather than $("#sidebox").css("top"), 0;?

Comment: @rontornambe it should be `$("#sidebox").css("top", 0)` but it does not solve the main issue at hand.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, i overlooked that somehow. Thanks a lot for poiting that out.